# Error: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am doing online hosting and this error will come:

> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

How can I solve it?

Answer (score -1):

This error can be solved by editing the application pool settings that you have deployed the project into. Go to advanced settings -> change the .Net Framework version = 4. I think this can solve your problem else refer this thread: